# What do French people use to say “gorgeous” besides beau/belle?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, choix-de-mot

To say someone is gorgeous what do people usually say? And for something nonliving? Would it just be “magnifique” and “merveilleux” and stuff like that?

Answer (score 4):

In French, we can translate "gorgeous" as different words depending on the context.
To describe a woman we got multiple words like "somptueuse" and "charmante".
For an object it could be "magnifique" and "merveilleux" as well as "raffiné" and "élegant".

Comment: could somptueux/charmant be used for men too? to say a man is gorgeous?

Comment: "somptueux" and "charmant" may be used for men, it just seemed unnatural for me to describe a man as gorgeous, but yes.

Comment: *Charmant(e)* can be used to qualify more than just the external look: you can say someone is *charmant* because they are extremely nice, helpful, compassionate, etc. It is very common to say eg "J'ai eu quelqu'un de charmant au téléphone" - obviously, you can't tell if this person looks good or not. Still, you can also add *sublime* to the list.

Answer (score 4):

For a drop dead kind of gorgeous woman, we could say *canon* :

'tain, elle est vraiment canon, la fille!

Applied to a man, I would use *beau gosse* :

Il est beau gosse

or :

C'est un beau gosse.

*Beau gosse* has been recently abbreviated in *bg* /beʒe/.  I first heard it two years ago used by my ten-year-old son.  It can be used as a form of address more or less ironically :

Alors, bg, ça va!

Answer (score 2):

French people often use the term "admirable" for something or someone good to admire. For the word georgous, you can say it "parfait".

Answer (score 0):

In a familiar context you would often hear the phrase "trop beau" or "trop belle". When used in that way "trop" conveys a meaning of intensification, there's no implied judgement or criticism.